# Why http://openbittorent.com/ can't be opened with firefox?

Tags: firefox, proxy

I have set global proxy with shadowsocks in my openwrt. Now almost every web page can be opened in my firefox. It is so strange that `http://openbittorent.com/` can not be opened. It can be pinged in my router's openwrt.

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ping  openbittorent.com
PING openbittorent.com (91.195.241.72): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 91.195.241.72: seq=0 ttl=49 time=295.391 ms
64 bytes from 91.195.241.72: seq=1 ttl=49 time=298.360 ms
```

To input `http://openbittorent.com/` in Firefox on one of local net'pc, no error info, nothing in Firefox, just blank. Why?

Comment: i think because website is **https** and you write **http**

Comment: @MohamedSlama most websites with SSL have redirects built in so that just putting in the URL (which would normally automatically have the HTTP appended) redirects to the HTTPS version of the site.

Comment: i don't know why redirecting not working but when i tried `openbittorent.com/` on both chrome and firefox give me white page i search for the website on google i found protocol is **https** i tried and it works their was a similar problem with `imdb` but fixed. @Zacharee1

Comment: @MohamedSlama The OP is trying to go to `openbitorent`. The actual site is `openbitorrent`. One vs. two Rs.

Comment: @Zacharee1 i didn't see spilling :) and website should be openbi**t**torrent not `openbitorrent` anyway i update my answer :)

Comment: Sorry, that's me making my common typo.

Answer (score 2):

The site is having some issues or you have misspelled the domain:

openbittoRRent.com

Comment: So then the site is having some issues :) I too get the white blank page , so it is not your router.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature is it working with changing to **https** ??

Comment: It is `https://openbittorrent.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Spelling and protocol are not correct so it should be :
 http**s**://openbit**t**orrent.com or you can simply google **openbitorrent** and it will correct its spelling.